# prevent last record in access table to be deleted

Tags: ms-access-2013

I made a loginform for my access database but how to prevent anyuser to delete the last record
Ex: if there is two records in login_table or more. The user can delete all the record but not the lastone

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do that:
1. Create constraint on your server side code to check whether there is only one record at the time of deleting the records.
2. Create a trigger on the table which prevents the user from deleting the last record.

Comment: Thank you but I'm new to access so can you help me to know how to check the last record then how prevebt deleting

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to accomplish this in Access 2013 would be to create a "Before Delete" data macro that looks like this:

```
If  DCount("*","Table1")<2  Then
    RaiseError
             Error Number  1
        Error Description  You cannot delete the last remaining record in this table.
End If
```

To create this data macro, open the table in Design View, then on the "Design" tab of the ribbon click "Create Data Macros" and choose "Before Delete". (Remember to replace "Table1" with the actual name of your table.)

Answer (score 0):

The previous record is saved in the table so it can be deleted. The record being entered is not actually saved in the table until the form is closed or an action is taken to enter another record.

On an entry form I create a duplicate table with the same fields. The entry form places the data temporarily into the first table. Then I created two queries. One to update from the temporary table to the secondary table. The second query clears the first table making it ready for new data entry. The action of the query requires to command entry to save the record prior to running the two queries. I perform this by creating a macro to perform the actions in sequence. 1. save record, 2 copy the data to the second table, 3 clear the first table.

You will have better control over the data.